# Listview adding 2 elements from JSoup

Tags: android, android-listview, jsoup

I have 2 elements  tags which i want to add to 2 edittexts of a listview.
How do i do that?

```
String[] from = new String[] {"col_1", "col_2"};
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.editText1, R.id.editText2 };

List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map;

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(test);
Elements tdsFromSecondColumn = doc.select("td:eq(0)"); 
Elements tdsFromSecondColumn1 = doc.select("td:eq(1)");

for (Element tdFromSecondColumn: tdsFromSecondColumn) {
     map = new HashMap<String, String>();
     map.put("col_1", tdFromSecondColumn.text()); 
     map.put("col_2", ?????);
     fillMaps.add(map);

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AndroidLogin.this, fillMaps, R.layout.test, from, to);
kp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that i would suggest you to create custom adapter for your ListView.

You know why i suggest to create a custom adapter? Just because of its one time practice, one you do it perfectly then it will be useful for any kind of ListView in future.

For creating a **custom adapter for ListView**, follow the below steps:

1. Create a listview row xml file (For your case, it will contain only 2 EditText only).
2. Now define a custom adapter class (and extends BaseAdapter) and inflate the above listview row file. And You need to override the **getView()** method for putting the desired value inside the EditText boxes.
3. Create an object of this custom adapter class and set it inside the ListView.

Comment: Hi Paresh,
Hmmm ok, i created the listview row xml file.
Could you give some more details about point 2 and 3? Maybe a example?
Thank you.

Comment: I hope you understand my answer properly and here is a bunch of articles for ListView: http://goo.gl/00Jhi, i try your best to learn this examples, as i told you earlier creating custom adapter is one time practice so go through it throughly

Comment: Hi Paresh,
I think i will dig into it, doesn`t look so difficult as i thought ;)

Comment: @Lars its not difficult and as i said earlier creating custom adapter is only 1 time practice then you can use the same adapter for GridView as well after little bit changes.

Comment: i already applied some code and it is running successfully.
I only have a problem with filling the listview correctly.
If your interested see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881884/asynctask-custombaseadapter-and-listview